# Intellij: How to find a method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to find what method was called when I tap on something. The project is huge and find it by myself will take a good amount of time. 
Is there any possible way to do that?
I'm using Android Studio and yeah I'm working with another person's project for the first time ever.

Comment: I think, when you select the method there will be a "jumpToSorce" Button

Comment: I mean I don't even know where this method is.

Comment: use Ctrl+G to find the usage of anything i.e Java,XML,method etc

Comment: And I don't know the name of the method. I want to find the way to tap something and debugger says "dude the method(); from Activity.class was called".

Comment: Try       Ctrl+Fun+F12 or Ctrl+F12

Answer (score 0):

How I do this:

1. Let's say that the button has some text. Let's  say, it is `Login`.
2. Go to the `strings.xml`, and find the text, matching the text on the button.
3. use `Find Usages` in Android Studio on the found string.
4. In layout XML file observe the button, which text is set to the `Login` string.
5. Use `Find Usages` on the ID of the button
6. Open the Java file, where the ID of the button is used (usually it is used in `findViewById()`)
7. use `Find Usages` on the `Button` object which is found by id.
8. Find the `setOnClickListener` of that button.
9. see, what is called in that listener.

Comment: Yeah, I do the same but this is another case. There's no way to find it through the XML because it has no text.

Comment: @Den, what it has then? You can do same thing, but with any other text on the screen related to the button somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this somehow answers your questions, but at least I found [**"Analyzing Data Flow"**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/analyzing-data-flow.html) very helpful in messed up projects.

[Here's](https://tips.seebrock3r.me/analyse-data-flows-without-the-debugger-android-studio-protips-3-ef2885aaffd9) a nice article concerning the feature by Sebastiano Poggi.

Also a gif demostrating the feature in action:

[image]

It's also accessible through context menu:

[image]

Comment: Well, this is not what I asked about but it's pretty useful, thanks.